# Multiple EditText values in Button

Tags: android

Is it possible to combine 4 strings into one Button with proper separation/styling between them?

For example,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Labal.png

Currently I have the values in a tablerow but I would like for it to act like a button.

Thanks.

**EDIT: Figured it out.**

Within the onclicklistener I added:

```
                    tr1.setBackgroundResource(drawable.list_selector_background);
```

where tr1 is my tablerow. (you will need to make the tablerow final for it to work).

I'm currently looking into a different list_selector color but this does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one button, I don't think so but you can put your 4 String in a layout,set a selector in background and add a clickListener on your layout.

Comment: I've heard of something about onDraw canvas being used but could not find a good resource on how to do it.

Comment: The onDraw method, it's a little tricky to do just that. The xml method with the layout, it's for me the easier method

Comment: I figured it out. Check main question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image that has the four strings correctly spaced, then put it in your drawables folder and apply it as a background for a button.

Or you can create a RelativeLayout with four buttons inside of it. Each of the four buttons has the text you want, and make them all go to the same place. You can space them evenly to where there is no empty room left between them.

Comment: Good suggestion. However, I want one click to light up the entire row. If you know what I mean.

Comment: Maybe you could use the RelativeLayout with four buttons, and every time that you click a button, call the other three buttons' `setSelected()` methods?

Comment: I actually figured it out. Check the main question if you're curious. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a [Custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781776/listview-custom-listview), it wouldn't be a button but you can still have an OnItemClickListener